# Magento 2 Override admin phtml

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, phtml, template-override

I've made a new module and I would like to override the
`vendor/magento/module-config/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/form/field/array.phtml`

I've copied the file in `app/code/myVendor/myModule/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/form/field/array.phtml`
and I've added this xml file in `app/code/myVendor/myModule/view/adminhtml/layout/config_form_field.xml:`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock class="myVendor\myModule\Block\System\Form\Field\Multi" name="config_field">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">myVendor_myModule::system/config/form/field/array.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

But it doesn't take my new file, it still takes the file from vendor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I was about to suggest that your module includes a `sequence` tag pointing to `Magento_Config` in the module xml which will tell Magento to load your module last, but then I saw something interesting - if your class extends `vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form/Field/FieldArray/AbstractFieldArray.php` then you will probably see that the abstract class has this:

```php
/**
 * @var string
*/
protected $_template = 'Magento_Config::system/config/form/field/array.phtml';
```

so you will need to ovewrite this property and add your template file there in your custom block.